# Ignore row if duplicate at CSV import

Tags: postgresql, csv

I was wondering if it possible? If a row for some reason cannot be imported
ex. duplicate primary key, wrong input type etc etc can it be ignored and move to the next row?

I'm getting this

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "team_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (team)=(DEN) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY team, line 23: "DEN,Denver,Rockets,A"
```

There's a lot of mistakes in the file and its a pretty big one, so is it possible to ignore the rows that can't be inserted?

Comment: a possible approach can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947327/to-ignore-duplicate-keys-during-copy-from-in-postgresql - would that be usable in your case?

Comment: that would solve the duplicate issue but how can i solve the invalid type one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [postgresql: \copy method enter valid entries and discard exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169372/postgresql-copy-method-enter-valid-entries-and-discard-exceptions)

Comment: This is oft-discussed, see the linked answers on the "possible duplicate" link I posted above.

Comment: Yes i managed to solve the duplicate issue, but is there any way to skip the invalid lines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore duplicates when importing from CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482695/ignore-duplicates-when-importing-from-csv)

Answer (score 3):

A solution that handles the duplicate key issue is described in [To ignore duplicate keys during 'copy from' in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947327/to-ignore-duplicate-keys-during-copy-from-in-postgresql) - in short using an unconstrained temp table and `select distinct on uniquefield` into the destination table.

Another way would involve using [pgLoader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader).  Unfortunately the documentation seems to have disappeared from the website, but there are several tutorial article on [the author's site](http://tapoueh.org/tags/pgloader).  It has rich functionality to help you read data with issues, and can do things like store rejected lines in a separate file, transform fields and so on.

Something that may not be obvious immediately: pgLoader version 2 is written in Python, version 3 is written in Lisp.  Both can be obtained from the GitHub page.