# Writing data flow to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I know that by doing:

```
COPY test FROM '/path/to/csv/example.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

I can import csv data to postgresql.

However, I do not have a static csv file. My csv file gets downloaded several times a day and it includes data which has previously been imported to the database. So, to get a consistent database I would have to `leave out` this old data.

My bestcase idea to realize this would be something like above. However, worstcase would be a java program manually checks each entry of the db with the csv file. Any recommendations for the implementation?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: You can `COPY` full file to temp table and then `INSERT ... SELECT ...` only new record to the actual table.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a bulk data merge, i.e. copy ignoring duplicates, or copy upsert. If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13947327/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump latest data to the temp table using [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) command and [MERGE](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MergeTestExamples) temp table with the live table.

If you are using JAVA program for execute COPY command, then try [CopyManager](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) API.