# Add lot of records to SQL Database if they are not already in with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an SQL DB (Postgree) with ~ 2000000  records in a table. And I have a CSV file with ~ 500000 rows. I need to check all records in CSV and add them to DB if they were not present before . I should check them by `name` field.

My question is what is the fastest way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019381/how-postgresql-copy-to-stdin-with-csv-do-on-conflic-do-update could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load your new rows into a staging table.
2. Index your staging and target tables on the `name` column
3. write a query like this:

   `INSERT INTO target (column list) 
   SELECT column list 
   FROM source 
   LEFT JOIN target 
     ON target.name = source.name 
   WHERE target.name IS NULL`

or

```
INSERT INTO target (<column list>)
SELECT <column list> FROM source
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * from target 
    WHERE target.name = source.name
)
```