# Import CSV to table in postgreSQL ignoring duplicates - Amazon AWS/RDS

Tags: postgresql, csv, duplicates, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I have a PostgreSQL hosted on AWS (RDS). I've created a couple tables and imported some .csv files to this tables using the "Import/Export" tool on PgAdmin4.

Monthly I´ll need to update the data on my tables, and I'll do that by uploading .csv files.

The issue that I'm facing right now is: I am trying to insert new data on a table from a .csv file, but I need to **ignore the duplicate values**.

I have found a way to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947327/to-ignore-duplicate-keys-during-copy-from-in-postgresql) (code below ) but the `copy` command does not work on PgAdmin. Copy only works if I use the import/export tool.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table 
ON COMMIT DROP
AS
SELECT * 
FROM indice-id-cnpj
WITH NO DATA;

COPY tmp_table FROM 'C:/Users/Win10/Desktop/Dados/ID-CNPJ.csv';

INSERT INTO indice-id-cnpj
SELECT *
FROM tmp_table
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

This is my first experience with PostgreSQL (apart from a subject in uni). I can deal with the issue by using excel and doing a little manual work, but I'm looking for a " long term " solution, on how to keep updating the tables using the .csv files, always ignoring the duplicates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use pgAdmin use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) instead. It is a better experience to boot.

Comment: Should have added, if you do use `psql` you will need to use `\copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I´ve found a solution.

As Adrian mentioned, I had to use psql.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table AS SELECT * FROM table-name WITH NO DATA;
\copy tmp_table FROM 'C:/Users/Win10/folder/filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV ENCODING 'UTF8' ;


INSERT INTO "table-name" SELECT * FROM tmp_table ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
DROP TABLE tmp_table;
```

Since I´m using psql it´s necessary to use the command `\copy` instead of `COPY`. Also, every command must finish with a ";" and it´s necessary to drop the `tmp_table` at the end.