# Bulk INSERT in Postgres in GO using pgx

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I am trying to bulk insert keys in db in go here is the code
**Key Struct**

```
type tempKey struct {
keyVal  string
lastKey int
```

}

**Test Keys**

```
data := []tempKey{
    {keyVal: "abc", lastKey: 10},
    {keyVal: "dns", lastKey: 11},
    {keyVal: "qwe", lastKey: 12},
    {keyVal: "dss", lastKey: 13},
    {keyVal: "xcmk", lastKey: 14},
}
```

**Insertion part**

```
dbUrl := "db url...."
conn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), dbUrl)
if err != nil {
    println("Errrorr...")
}
defer conn.Close(context.Background())
sqlStr := "INSERT INTO keys (keyval,lastval) VALUES "
dollars := ""
vals := []interface{}{}
count := 1
for _, row := range data {
    dollars = fmt.Sprintf("%s($%d, $%d),", dollars, count, count+1)
    vals = append(vals, row.keyVal, row.lastKey)
    count += 2
}
sqlStr += dollars
sqlStr = sqlStr[0 : len(sqlStr)-1]
fmt.Printf("%s \n", sqlStr)

_, erro := conn.Exec(context.Background(), sqlStr, vals)
if erro != nil {
    fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, "Error : \n", erro)
}
```

on running it throws error: **expected 10 arguments, got 1**

What is the correct way of bulk inserting.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are crafting the SQL statement by hand, which is fine, but you are not leveraging `pgx` which can help with this (see below).

Appending to the SQL string like so can be inefficient for large inputs

```
dollars = fmt.Sprintf("%s($%d, $%d),", dollars, count, count+1)
```

but also the final value has a trailing `,` where instead you need a termination character `;` to indicate the end of the statement.

BTW this string truncation line is redundant:

```
sqlStr = sqlStr[0 : len(sqlStr)-1] // this is a NOOP
```

Anyway, better to use something more performant like [strings.Builder](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Builder) when crafting long strings.

---

From the `pgx` docs, use [pgx.Conn.CopyFrom](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx#Conn.CopyFrom):

```
func (c *Conn) CopyFrom(tableName Identifier, columnNames []string, rowSrc CopyFromSource) (int, error)
```

> CopyFrom uses the PostgreSQL copy protocol to perform bulk data
> insertion. It returns the number of rows copied and an error.

[example usage](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx#hdr-Copy_Protocol) of Copy:

```
rows := [][]interface{}{
    {"John", "Smith", int32(36)},
    {"Jane", "Doe", int32(29)},
}

copyCount, err := conn.CopyFrom(
    pgx.Identifier{"people"},
    []string{"first_name", "last_name", "age"},
    pgx.CopyFromRows(rows),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for additional info also..... I wasn't aware of Copy til now....made it worked

Comment: @AnswerRex it can be a PK violation on CopyFrom depending on tables structure. If it is your case then create temp table on session, do bulk insert there and then do `select to maintable from temp on conflict do nothing`. See details in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947327/to-ignore-duplicate-keys-during-copy-from-in-postgresql

Answer (score 16):

use batch (https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/master/batch_test.go):

```
batch := &pgx.Batch{}
batch.Queue("insert into ledger(description, amount) values($1, $2)", "q1", 1)
batch.Queue("insert into ledger(description, amount) values($1, $2)", "q2", 2)
br := conn.SendBatch(context.Background(), batch)
```

Comment: Thanks....Its simple and worked like charm but I have doubt does this have any performance hits from the answer of @colm.anseo.

Comment: yes. It slower than CopyFrom.

Comment: Batch is slower than CopyFrom. But the usage depends on business case. If you have different inserts into multiple tables then it probably make sense to use batch. If you need maximum insertion rate into single table, then of course CopyFrom.