# Bulk Insert PostGis Geometry using pgx.copyFrom or pgx.Batch

Tags: postgresql, go, postgis, pgx

I've found the way to make a bulk insert with classic postgres types from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70823397/1216281) and it works like a charm.
But for whatever reason, i struggle to make it work when trying to insert geometry points:

### using pgx.CopyFromRows

```golang
rows := [][]interface{}{
        {"John", "ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.23,2.34), 4326)"},
        {"Jane", "ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.10,2.12), 4326)"},
    }

    // GetSession return a *pgxpool.Pool
    copyCount, err := postgres.GetSession().CopyFrom(
        context.Background(),
        pgx.Identifier{"test_db"},
        []string{"first_name", "location"},
        pgx.CopyFromRows(rows),
    )
```

this gives me back

```
"ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered. (SQLSTATE XX000)"
```

### using pgx.Batch:

```golang
batch := &pgx.Batch{}
    batch.Queue("insert into people(first_name, location) values($1, $2)", "Bob", "ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.23,1.34), 4326)")
    batch.Queue("insert into people(first_name, location) values($1, $2)", "John", "ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.23,1.34), 4326)")
    batchResult := postgres.GetSession().SendBatch(context.Background(), batch)
    _, err := batchResult.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return rest_errors.NewInternalServerError("Error processing batch insert", err)
    }
    batchResult.Close()
```

I get this error

```
Error processing batch insert - parse error - invalid geometry (SQLSTATE XX000)
```

#### db creation script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test_db
(
    first_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    location geometry
)
```

Thank you so much